# How can I simulate resize in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I simulate resize in Angular without jquery?

Before, I did it like:

```
$(window).resize();
```

And second questions about focus()
When I try to focus element:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('.kb-active')).focus();
```

Console log: Error: angular.element(...).focus is not a function

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Angular ships with jqLite. If you need jQuery you need to assure that jQuery is loaded before angular. Than angular uses jQuery.

For reference the jqLite documentation is here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/function/angular.element

Which states that `.focus()` is not supported. If you load jQuery you can use `.focus()` and `.resize()`.

Comment: I understand this. My task is avoid jquery. With jquery all work very good.

Comment: Well, if you want the functionality from jQuery without using jQuery you are in a little bit of trouble :)